# Ссылка на внешний ключ пуста

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework

Я создал две модели с помощью Code First.

```
public class User
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long Name { get; set; }
}

public class Article
{
    public long Id{ get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

При создании новой сущности всё добавляется в БД, там есть столбец который указывает на Id User'а.

Но вот беда при обращении к article.User, ссылка User равна нулю.
Использую PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все свойства, указывающие на другие таблицы, называются полями навигации. По-умолчанию Entity не загружает данные по полям навигации.
Для того чтобы их загрузить нужно использовать методы `Include(a => a.NavField)`. А так же `ThenInclude(a => a.NavField)` для загрузки по уровню иерархии(т.е. для полей навигации в связанных таблицах). Эти методы применяются при выборке данных.

Есть способ попроще:
можно использовать `AutoInclude()` при описании контекста в переопределяемом методе `OnModelCreating(...)`
Пример:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
...
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Article>().Navigation(a => a.User).AutoInclude();
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Тогда при запросе к таблице **Article** данные по связям подтянутся автоматически.

Так же можно использовать метод `UseLazyLoadingProxies()` из состава пакета `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies` для ленивой загрузки данных.

Answer (score 1):

Для загрузки связанных данных необходимо использовать метод Include().

Вот тут подробное описание:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager